# Lower side of print rough on personal protection print

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, support-structures

I’m new to 3D printing and printed a few things that came out fine on my Ender 3. But when I print something like a cat protection baton, Kubota self-protection or anything that will have a “floating surface” it comes out rough.

[image]

Comment: In order to help find a solution, please [edit] in more information such as material, print settings, temperatures, what have you tried, etc. The more information you give, the more likely a solution can be achieved. Also, what do you mean by "Floating service"? Do you mean to say 'floating surface'?

Comment: do you use support? how is the support configurated? What are your print settings? can you show us a picture of your slice?

Answer (score 3):

FFF 3D printing doesn't work with "floating surfaces". It comes out rough because the filaments are being extruded in space and sagging away from their intended position as the filament is hot and liquid (as in a low viscosity).

To fix this, you need tell your slicer to add support structures so that it is not "floating", and then break away (and possibly sand) the support structures when the print is completed.

Alternately, you can manually add support structures to the part before slicing.  If the "floating surface" is horizontal, one or more thin wall vertical supports would allow the area to be bridged.  There needs to be at least be one vertical support at each end of the bridge.  You may need to add more in the middle if the span is too long and sags.